# What is the word for a person who counts?

Tags: nouns

What is the single word for a person who counts?

Comment: How about "enumerator"?  Could an enumerator count something other than people?

Comment: Are you asking for what you call some one who is doing counting of things, or about someone who who is important?

Comment: Hey Mister tallyman, tally me banana.

Comment: Please define what you mean by *count*. I could give the answer *important*, but I'm fairly sure that's not the sense of *a person who counts* that you have in mind.

Answer (score 1):

I find this from [Oxford Dictinoaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/counter)

**counter**, n
3.1 A person who counts something, for example votes in an election.

I also find these from the *Oxford English Dictionary*, perhaps now absolete or rare?

**accountant**, adj. and n.
...A person who counts or enumerates;

**reckoner**, n.
... esp. a person who counts or calculates;
...Later more generally: a person who counts or keeps tally of anything, ...